# Convention of Fourier transformation mattered in calculating the vacuum expectation value

Tags: field-theory, definition, conventions, fourier-transform, propagator

In the Peskin's textbook page xxi the notation and convention chapter, the Fourier transformation was defined to be
$$f(x)=\int \frac{d^4 k}{(2\pi)^4} e^{-ik x}\tilde f (k)$$
$$\tilde f(k)=\int d^4 x e^{ik x} f (x)$$
in contrary to the "standard" definition where
$$f(x)=\int \frac{d^4 k}{(2\pi)^4} e^{ik x}\tilde f (k)$$
$$\tilde f(k)=\int d^4 x e^{-ik x} f (x).$$
(the main difference was the sign but not the $2\pi$ factor)

Consider to rewrite the equation of a propagator with
$$D_F(x-y)=\int \frac{dk^4}{(2\pi)^4} \frac{ie^{-ik(x-y)}}{k^2-m^2 +i\epsilon}$$
defined in Peskin Eq. 9.27, and recognize the Fourier mode of the propagator
$$\tilde D_F(k)= \frac{i}{k^2-m^2 +i\epsilon}$$
This, following the book's convention, had lead to
$$\int dy^4 D(x-y) j(y) = \int dy^4  \int \frac{dk_1^4}{(2\pi)^4} e^{-ik_1(x-y)}  \tilde D_F(k_1) 
i\int \frac{dp_1^4}{(2\pi)^4} e^{-ip_1y} \tilde j(p_1) $$
$$\int dy^4 D(x-y) j(y) = \int dk_1^4  \delta^{(4)}(k_1-p_1) e^{-ik_1(x)}  \tilde D_F(k_1) 
i\int \frac{dp_1^4}{(2\pi)^4}  \tilde j(p_1) $$
the momentum carried by $\tilde D_F(k_1)$ and $\tilde j(p_1)$ was the same, instead of the standard $j(-k)\phi(k)$  that one had seen. Though in this case $\tilde D_F(k)=\tilde D_F(-k)$ similar procedure happen to $\tilde S_F(k)$ as well.

This seemed to have created a dilemma.

Why the propagator $\tilde D_F(k)$ was not in the opposite sign as $\tilde j(p_1)$? Does convention of Fourier transformation matter in calculating the vacuum expectation value? (The book usually pay lots of attention to the $g$ sign $\eta$ matrix, but this might be a case where the convention in the Fourier transformation matters so just to check. )

Answer (score 2):

First, note that Peskin and Schroeder's Fourier transform conventions *are* the usual conventions chosen in physics. They only look odd because of Einstein summation and the $(+,-,-,-)$ metric. Writing out the fourier transforms explicitly,
$$
f(x) = \int \frac{d^4 k}{(2\pi)^4} e^{-i (\omega t - \vec{k} \cdot \vec{x})} \tilde{f}(k) = \int \frac{d^4 k}{(2\pi)^4} e^{i (\vec{k} \cdot \vec{x} - \omega t)} \tilde{f}(k) 
$$

Second: clearly the issue you're raising has nothing to do with sign conventions. First note that if you chose the opposite sign convention, clearly you would run into the same issue.

But perhaps most importantly: the answer you're getting regarding the relation of the signs is exactly what you'd expect on general Fourier transform consideration. Recall the following "theorem", which is quite easy to prove: the Fourier transform of a convolution of two functions is equal to the product of their Fourier transforms:
$$
\int dy \, f(x-y) g(y) \xrightarrow{\text{F.T.}} \tilde{f}(k) \tilde{g}(k)
$$
That's exactly what's happening here. What you might have in mind is the following sort of equation:
$$
\int d^4 x \, d^4 y \, J(x) D_F(x-y) J(y) = \int \frac{d^4 k}{(2\pi)^4} J(-k) D_F(k) J(k)
$$
where one of the $J$'s has the opposite sign in the argument. You can check that this works out just fine, in P&S or any other Fourier transform convention.